# Вывод значений Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

Хочу вывести на страницы данный в таком формате: `[{'group_name': <>, 'date': [<>,<>,... ,<>], 'time': <>}, ...]`, используя Jinja2. Сервер данные отправляет, ошибок не возникает, но данные не отображаются.

Допустим, пытаюсь вывести group_name.

```
<ul>
  {% for name in data['group_name'] %}
    <li>{{ name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Что не так?

Comment: `data['group_name']` не существует, потому что `data` это, видимо, список. Существует `data[0]`, `data[1]` или `{% for item in data %}`, но никакого `data['group_name']` нету

Answer (score 1):

Просто неверное обращение к объекту.
Корректным будет следующее:

```
<ul>
  {% for entry in data %}
     <li>{{ entry['group_name'] }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```